# Acer GD245HQ not playing HDMI audio over AUDIO OUT jack

Tags: audio, display, hdmi

I have an `Acer GD245HQ` monitor and I want to transform it into a DTV. For now that I don't have an HDMI decoder at hand, I'm playing with my computer.

The idea is simple: get audio and video from DTV decoder via HDMI, and since the monitor is not equipped with embedded speakers (unlike the `Philips 240BW` monitor), attach cheap external speakers to it.

My desktop computer is equipped with a `760GTX` card and I run Windows 8. I connected the Acer monitor via HDMI, extended the desktop to it and then checked the monitor as primary audio output in Control Panel's Audio settings.

Playing some music with Windows Media Player didn't result in what I expected: no music was actually playing in my earphones.

I retried the experiment with the `LG 37LF75` HDTV: it worked as expected

[image: Audio configuration]

From [Acer](https://acer-za.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14258/%7E/using-the-audio-output-of-the-gd245hq-monitor)

> You can use the audio output to send the HDMI audio input to external speakers. The audio output connector is in fact active when the screen is connected via HDMI.

I don't know what's wrong in my setup. I'm sure that the earphones work. **How do I play audio from HDMI with that monitor?**

- Cost of stand-alone 24" DTV: 175€
- Cost of HD DTV decoder: 50€
- Satisfaction: priceless!

## Update

I tried with an HD DTV decoder via HDMI and I was able to play audio via jack out. I cannot explain myself why I couldn't play computer audio at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because **I** can no longer validate answers (see http://meta.superuser.com/a/4196/53108)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing HDMI cable worked. I don't know why, but I had to buy a new one.